# Error when merging records

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I'm getting an error when trying to merge any two records. This seems to have started after I deleted a large number of records. Here's the error message the user gets:

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

I did a backtrace but I don't really know how to read it to glean any useful information. I'm hoping that someone with experience reading these things can enlighten me.

#0 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()

#1 internal function: CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))

#2 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))

#3 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495...")

#4 /home/websitename/public_html/wcc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495...")

#5 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495...", "DB_Error", TRUE)

#6 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1034 ** Incorrect key file for table 'log_civicrm_entity_tag'; try to repair it")

#7 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()

#8 /home/websitename/public_html/wcc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495")

#9 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495")

#10 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495")

#11 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495")

#12 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1192): CRM_Core_DAO->query("UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495", TRUE)

#13 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(507): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("UPDATE IGNORE civicrm_entity_tag SET entity_id = 9769 WHERE entity_id = 89495", (Array:0), TRUE, NULL, TRUE)

#14 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(1344): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::moveContactBelongings("9769", "89495", (Array:3), (Array:0))

#15 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Merge.php(330): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::moveAllBelongings("9769", "89495", (Array:26))

#16 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(345): CRM_Contact_Form_Merge->postProcess()

#17 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(164): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()

#18 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge), "next", "Next")

#19 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge), "next")

#20 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge), "next")

#21 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")

#22 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(115): CRM_Core_Controller->run()

#23 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(286): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Merge", "Merge Contact", NULL)

#24 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))

#25 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

#26 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

#27 internal function: civicrm_invoke("contact", "merge")

#28 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))

#29 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()

#30 {main}

Comment: What version are you on? Any extensions active? I was running into a similar error on merges and didn't have much trouble identifying the issue -- but upgraded to 4.7 to take advantage of the merge improvements, and at this point things are working much better on that front.

Comment: I'm on 4.6.9. No extensions. That's a good note on upgrading to 4.7, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a quick glance but it looks like you might have a log record (in table log_civicrm_entity_tag)for a contact that you deleted based on this:

```
#6 /home/websitename/public_html/subdomainname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1034 ** Incorrect key file for table 'log_civicrm_entity_tag'; try to repair it")
```

I think there is a tag linked to a contact that no longer exists in your log file?

Comment: It indeed logging-related. I turned off logging, retried a few merges, and they succeeded. Now I just have to decide how much I actually need logging.

Comment: Cool! Glad I did spot the right track in a blink for a change :-)